# Problem when trying to execute a java file after compiling with UTF8 encoding

Tags: java, terminal, compilation, javac, execute

i am currently trying to run a java file in the terminal inside the corresponding package, which i created in eclipse (so its not the default package). However, the problem began after i tried to compile my file with:

```
javac Übung13.java
```

This just produced the following output:

```
▄bung13.java:2: error: illegal character: '\u00bc'
package ├╝bung1;
```

Shortly, i found out, that the cause was the || character, which is equivalent to the "or"-operator in boolean algebra. I then tried :

```
javac -encoding UTF8 Übung13.java
```

There was no output, therefore i thought, that it compiled whithout any problems, and there was also an Übung13.class file inside the package, which also emphasized that i was right. But when i try to execute my java file, then it prints the following output:

```
java Übung13
Fehler: Hauptklasse Übung13 konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden
Ursache: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: übung1/Übung13 (wrong name: Übung13)
```

This implies that my package contains no class, but this cant be true, since i compiled the file successfully. This is the point where i also cant find any solutions. Help would be appreciated greatly.

Here is the source code of my java file in case that there are any mistakes, but the file ran without any errors in the eclipese IDE, so i highly doubt that.

```
// -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
package übung1;

public class Übung13 {
    
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            System.out.println("Das erste Kommandozeilenargument ist: " + args[0]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Keine Kommandozeilenargumente vorhanden.");
        }
        /*
         * args ist eine variable welche für das Terminal steht bzw. man kann sie als array betrachten 
         * welcher als index die zeilen angibt.  
         */
        System.out.println(args.length);
        //Beispiel für eine Interaktion mit dem Terminal um die Summe zweier zahlen zu errechnen
        try {
         if (args.length == 0 || args.length == 1) {
             
         }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.print("Falsche Eingabe");
        };
        
         
    }
    

}
```

Also my path to the java file:
`eclipse-workspace\Übungen\src\übung1`

1.

```
javac Übung13.java
```

2. 

```
javac -encoding UTF8 Übung13.java
```

3. 

```
java übung1.Übung13
```

4. 

```
java Übung13.java
```

Comment: read through your question and there are several things that dont add up. `\u00bc` is the unicode character for `¼` also your error message is complaining about the `Ü` in classname. Its hard to get a piccture of this but you can change the name of your compiled jar to `.zip`and extract its contents to look at what the directory structure looks like inside the jar-file. But its very hard to help since you have not supplied any simple instructions how to reproduce.

Comment: `java -XshowSettings:all 2>&1 | findstr "encoding"`

Comment: the class is declared to be in the package called `übung1` - so it must be executed as `java übung1.Übung13` but from the folder that contains `übung1`, that is, from `eclipse-workspace\Übungen\src` assuming that `Übung13.class` was created in `eclipse-workspace\Übungen\src\übung1` (or `eclipse-workspace\Übungen\src` must be added to the CLASSPATH: java -cp eclipse-workspace\Übungen\src übung1.Übung13`)  -- anyway strongly discouraged to use Umlaute (or similar) in package or class names - but note that eclipse usually is configured to use a different folder for generated .class files

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use umlauts or other diacritics in package or class names as they are not very portable. But your code *should* work per the comments of @user85421

Answer (score 1):

First, I’ll point out something interesting:  Java SE does not have a String class.

Java *does* have class named java.lang.String.  When you compile code, the compiler automatically inserts `import java.lang.*;`, which means wherever the word String appears in code, it is treated as shorthand for `java.lang.String`.

Why is this relevant?  Because your program does not have a class named Übung13.  Your program does have a class named `übung1.Übung13`.

So, the first thing to note is that it is *never* correct to just use “Übung13” by itself.  The only correct way to run your program is #3 in your question:  `java übung1.Übung13`

Why didn’t it work?  Because your [current directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) does not contain an Übung13 class *in the übung1 package.*

Before running the program, change to the parent directory:

```
cd ..
```

Then `java übung1.Übung13` should work.

A general rule is that if the command `dir übung1\Übung13.class` displays a file, you can run the above java command.  If that dir command does not list any files, you are in the wrong current directory, and Java will not recognize your class.

The reason for this is that the Java classpath—the sequence of directories and .jar files which Java searches for classes—is always the current directory, unless you explicitly specify a classpath with the `-cp` or `--class-path` option.  If the current directory contains Übung13.java, then the current directory does not contain a übung1.Übung13 class.

Comment: *A general rule is that if the command dir übung1\Übung13.class ....* I don't want to nitpick but that class might be in the default package but its file just happen to be in that directory.

Comment: @g00se `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: übung1/Übung13 (wrong name: Übung13)` suggests otherwise.

Comment: Ah no, I'm making a different point: that you can't *necessarily* infer that the class `Übung13` is in package `übung1` merely from the name of its parent directory. You *were* referring to "A general rule" Your point is probably sound *for a specific instance*

Comment: Your answer is highly interesting, but how can a `Ü` be a valid character in a Java class name? I found the [following definition](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javatm-how-to/9780133813036/ch02lev2sec5.html): "A class name is an identifier—a series of characters consisting of **letters**, digits, underscores (_) and dollar signs ($) that does not begin with a digit and does not contain spaces". Hence, whether or not an `Ü` (or, say, a `静`) is considered a letter, is at best dependent on the locale, and such a program would face portability issues.

Comment: @user1934428 You are correct.  Whether Java treats a character as a letter will depend on correctly recognizing that letter, which means the Java compiler needs to know the encoding of the source file.  At runtime, it shouldn’t matter;  if the operating system sees the filename correctly, Java most likely will, too.

Comment: The encoding is not enough. It also needs to know the locale, because the locale tells you for instance, what is a letter, and whether we have an upper or lower case letter. If you only look at the encoding, can we tell whether i.e. `ß8` or `クラス` are valid class names? The locale also defines, what is regarded as digit; think of a class named　`C2２2`, or `C2ニ2`. This means that when delivering your program, you have to tell your user what locale he can run it in.

Comment: @user1934428 Not correct.  The Unicode Character Database designates every codepoint’s category.  If the category starts with ‘L’, it is considered a letter, regardless of locale.

Comment: BTW you forgot the CLASSPATH environment variable in the last paragraph

Comment: @user85421 I know.  I was trying to limit the scope, rather than providing exhaustive tool documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I find this a bit confusing, because for instance [`二`](https://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%E4%BA%8C) is categorized as _other letter_ (whatever the _other_ is supposed to mean), although the character is also used as a digit. I see that this is not dependent on the locale, but I still wonder whether Java would allow an identifier to start with 二....